# How to call multiple arrays from a function in PHP 5.6?

Tags: php, arrays, string, function

I have a php file, say A.php, where I have defined a function log_campaign_activity, which is returning 2-arrays, as shown below:

```
function log_campaign_activity($identifier, $activity, $update=true, $clicked_url_key=null) {

$return_array = array();

$db = DBManagerFactory::getInstance();



 //check to see if the identifier has been replaced with Banner string
if($identifier == 'BANNER' && isset($clicked_url_key)  && !empty($clicked_url_key))
{
    // create md5 encrypted string using the client ip, this will be used for tracker id purposes
    $enc_id = 'BNR'.md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    //default the identifier to ip address
    $identifier = $enc_id;

    //if user has chosen to not use this mode of id generation, then replace identifier with plain guid.
    //difference is that guid will generate a new campaign log for EACH CLICK!!
    //encrypted generation will generate 1 campaign log and update the hit counter for each click
    if(isset($sugar_config['campaign_banner_id_generation'])  && $sugar_config['campaign_banner_id_generation'] != 'md5'){
        $identifier = create_guid();
    }

    //retrieve campaign log.
    $trkr_query = "select * from campaign_log where target_tracker_key='$identifier' and related_id = '$clicked_url_key'";
    $current_trkr=$db->query($trkr_query);
    $row=$db->fetchByAssoc($current_trkr);

    //if campaign log is not retrieved (this is a new ip address or we have chosen to create
    //unique entries for each click
    if($row==null  || empty($row)){


            //retrieve campaign id
            $trkr_query = "select ct.campaign_id from campaign_trkrs ct, campaigns c where c.id = ct.campaign_id and ct.id = '$clicked_url_key'";
            $current_trkr=$db->query($trkr_query);
            $row=$db->fetchByAssoc($current_trkr);


            //create new campaign log with minimal info.  Note that we are creating new unique id
            //as target id, since we do not link banner/web campaigns to any users

            $data['target_id']="'" . create_guid() . "'";
            $data['target_type']= "'Prospects'";
            $data['id']="'" . create_guid() . "'";
            $data['campaign_id']="'" . $row['campaign_id'] . "'";
            $data['target_tracker_key']="'" . $identifier . "'";
            $data['activity_type']="'" .  $activity . "'";
            $data['activity_date']="'" . TimeDate::getInstance()->nowDb() . "'";
            $data['hits']=1;
            $data['deleted']=0;
            if (!empty($clicked_url_key)) {
                $data['related_id']="'".$clicked_url_key."'";
                $data['related_type']="'".'CampaignTrackers'."'";
            }

            //values for return array..
            $return_array['target_id']=$data['target_id'];
            $return_array['target_type']=$data['target_type'];

            //create insert query for new campaign log
            $insert_query="INSERT into campaign_log (" . implode(",",array_keys($data)) . ")";
            $insert_query.=" VALUES  (" . implode(",",array_values($data)) . ")";
            $db->query($insert_query);
        }else{

            //campaign log already exists, so just set the return array and update hits column
            $return_array['target_id']= $row['target_id'];
            $return_array['target_type']= $row['target_type'];
            $query1="update campaign_log set hits=hits+1 where id='{$row['id']}'";
            $current=$db->query($query1);


       }

    //return array and exit
    return $return_array;

}
```

You can observe that in the end, it is returning 2-arrays:

- $return_array['target_id']= $row['target_id'];
- $return_array['target_type']= $row['target_type'];

I want to call this function and store these values in 2-variables of another php-file, say B.php:

- $targetID
- $targetType

How can I do this? What is better method?

With thanks,

RK

Answer (score 0):

In B.php

```
//Require A.php, so you can call your function
require_once("A.php"); 

//Call your function with needed parameters
$result = log_campaign_activity($param1, $param2, $param3...); 

//Save result into vars
$targetID = $result["target_id"];
$targetType = $result["target_type"];
```